Common `tsconfig` for all projects/workspaces
I'm re-organizing several unrelated typescript projects into a mono-repo structure. Currently I have a tsconfig.json file in each workspace, which are all identical. I would like to have a "common" tsconfig in the base folder instead of all the project tsconfigs. Here's an example of my project structure:
packages/
| foo/
| | src/
| | | index.ts
| | package.json
| | tsconfig.json
| bar/
| | src/
| | | index.ts
| | package.json
| | tsconfig.json
| asd/
| | src/
| | | index.ts
| | package.json
| | tsconfig.json
package.json

./packages/foo/tsconfig.json (for example):
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
  ],
}

If I leave the file as-is, and move it to ./, then it cannot find any inputs, presumably because it is looking for ./src which doesn't exist.
I would love to create a ./tsconfig.json like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "$PWD/dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "$PWD/types",
  },
  "include": [
    "$PWD/src",
  ],
}

Unfortunately, I get this error:
error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file '/<my_path>/tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["$PWD/src"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["$PWD/dist","$PWD/types"]'.

Is there a way I can have the paths within tsconfig auto-expand to whatever directory I'm working in or otherwise use a single tsconfig file for all my projects?

You can create a base tsconfig.json and extend it in tsconfig.{project}.json by using extends.
To build {project}, run tsc --project tsconfig.{project}.json.
i.e.,
tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "types",
    },
    "include": [
        "src",
    ],
}

tsconfig.foo.json
{
    "extends": "tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declarationDir": "foo/dir"
    },
    "include": [
        "foo/src",
    ],
}

To build foo: tsc --project tsconfig.foo.json

Thanks, although I think there is an error in this post: tsconfig.json:7:5 - error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'destinationDir'. Also, I was looking to remove tsconfig.{project}.json entirely. Doing it this way still means I need to create a new, identical tsconfig for each project.

Sorry it should have been declarationDir not destinationDir. But noted on your point about wanting to remove tsconfig.foo.json. In that case, you could always leverage the CLI arguments --declarationDir and --include. For example, tsc --declarationDir foo/dir --include foo/dir
